# What is the best approach when you have 2 rules in CSS with the exact same properties except for one?

Tags: css, frontend

Let's say you have these two rules:

```
.box1 {
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin: 1rem;
        
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);

.box2 {
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin: 1rem;
        
        color: rgb(71, 131, 250);
```

And you really need each one to have its respective color.

My question is:

Is the next code a correct approach?

```
.box1, .box2 {
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin: 1rem;
        
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
} 

.box2 {
        color: rgb(71, 131, 250);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since those are classes, I actualy think you could have just one class, `.box`, for example, with all those properties, and then `.box2` with the custom color.

```
.box {
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin: 1rem;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
} 

.box2 {
        color: rgb(71, 131, 250);
}
```

A straight answer to your question would be: **yes. You have the correct approach.** Always try to write as less code as possible.

**EDIT:** as pointed out in the comments by ray, in case I was not clear, you will apply both classes when you can to alternate color, as such:

```
<div class=“box box2”>
```

Comment: Just to be clear: You’d apply both classes when you want the alternate color: `<div class=“box box2”>`.